# How to add support for additional codects to android's MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, codec, video-codecs

According to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) there is a limited number of supported audio and video codecs. How to add support for other codecs and extend the supported media formats on android? Are there other alternative for multimedia playback?

Comment: Are you looking for video or audio?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I will probably need to add support for both video and audio codecs.